# Wordpress newbie seeking a name and guidance

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've recently began to learn css and php, in attempt to create a wordpress site.
I've pretty much been up 24/7 for 2 weeks trying to figure it all out.
Today while I was browsing for ideas I stumbled on my own thought...
And after Googling for what felt like an eternity I thought I'd give this site a try... (It's just confusing to google something when you have no clue what it could be called.)
Is there an "easy" way to hide all of the site's content until a button is pressed?

For instance, http://gyazo.com/6645edf04777af0f375b662db452d33f
... Let's say that image is the entire site, until I press the arrow facing down. It then "reveals" the rest of the site, in some fancy way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider learning JavaScript next. I know it's a lot to learn all at the same time, but there are many JavaScript libraries that make it easier to do what you're describing, one popular example is jQuery.

Comment: I definitely will, starting right away! Thank you for a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can do this with jquery which is a JavaScript library.

> **Note:** If you're not familiar with jQuery, you'll have to put this inside your `<head>` tag:
>  `<script
>   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
>   
>  To call the JQuery library from Googgle. **Learn more about [jQuery here](https://jquery.com/)**

This `<script>` should go to your header or it can also be place on the footer:

```
<script>
$(".showMsg").click(function () {
    $('#website').fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

Your HTML

```
<button class="showMsg">Click Me</button>

<div id="website">
    <p>
        ... Content here ...
    </p>
</div>
```

And you also need to set `display:none;` for `#website` so it won't start visible

```
#website {
    display:none;
}
```

**Here's an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/3182nk34/)**

Comment: Worked like a charm, after figuring for a couple minutes.
Thanks for the detailed info!


Edit: Also, I'm not sure if lack of sleep ruined my judgement, but is the scripted button in the "online example" not supposed to work?

Comment: @CarvingJohnson the jsfiddle example is just missing the jQuery library